# Does Vuetify's data-table work with Static Site Generation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, static-site-generation, vuetify-datatable

Can I use an SSG tool for Vue.js, like Nuxt, to generate a single-page application using Vuetify and have its data-table component (instantiated with `v-data-table`) work, i.e. be able to display tabular data loaded as JSON (via a totally separate REST API, nowhere near Vue.js), enable editing its rows and having script handlers make REST calls in response to edit events which data-table provides? If so, what steps does that involve?

Or am I confused about the requirements, e.g. the meaning of static? (I understand it as content, i.e. HTML mostly, being ready on the server and send in response to requests, as opposed to generated on the fly. But maybe the in Vue.js it means something different.)

Comment: Yes, In the context of a static site generation tool like Nuxt.js, "static" means that the HTML, JavaScript, and other assets for your site are generated at build time and then deployed to a server, rather than being generated on the fly;